# How to use string in path to object?

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I need to use string in path to object.

```
var nameOfTrails:String = "trail"+this.getDepth();
_parent.createEmptyMovieClip(nameOfTrails,this.getDepth()+1);
_parent.nameOfTrails.beginFill(FillColor,FillAlpha);
```

How to do this in ActionScript 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you case you could access instance you created like this:

```
    _parent[nameOfTrails]
```

The point is that you can access an object using string with his name by searching proper object for property with that name.

In your example you creating variable with id of `nameOfTrails` value inside some object which relate to your current code scope as parent, and put  reference to newly created MovieClip inside this variable. So now, object referenced by `_parent` have property named for example 'trail0' (by the way `this.getDepth()` is not so smart thing to do then you creating objects in other scope). All you need to do now is access that property using classical 'give me property of that object by his key' style - `obj['propertyName']` and voila.

Comment: Thank you, Aspiro! You helped me really much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this :

```
for(var i:Number = 0; i < 3; i++){
    var movie_clip:MovieClip = this.createEmptyMovieClip('movie_clip_' + i, i);
        movie_clip._y = i * 22;

    var text_field:TextField = movie_clip.createTextField('text_field', 0, 0, 0, 120, 18); 
        text_field.text = 'movie clip : ' + i;
}

var j:Number = 2;
trace(this['movie_clip_' + j].text_field.text);     // gives : movie clip : 2
trace(eval('movie_clip_' + 1).text_field.text);     // gives : movie clip : 1
```

For more details, take a look on the [eval function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7f8a.html).

Hope that can help.